# ECS Fargate with Dockerized container nginx not loading static files

Tags: react-native, nginx, web-applications, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a webapp made in React and when I run the dockerimage locally, it works fine. No issues. When I deploy it to ECS Fargate with nginx it gives me a lot of weird errors.

Specifically, it cannot find the static assets. Here is my nginx file:

```
server {
listen       ${PORT:-80};
server_name  _;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html;

location / {
    try_files $$uri /index.html;
}
```

I am unsure what to change here, or in my yml files to get it to access the static stuff on ECS.

The error I am getting is the following:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: A 503 response indicates that there should be a more informative error in the server's logs. Did you check the Nginx logs?

Comment: we ended up switching from nginx to express and that fixed the problem. But Im a new developer and I still do not quit understand why nginx was having issues serving the static files on ECS fargate.... Is there any place I can read up on this and understand the issue or could someone explain it to a novice?

Comment: Without looking at the error logs in Nginx to see what the problem was, what would you research? Nginx can normally serve static files just fine. In every situation like this you need to find exact error logs before you can start any sort of investigation into the issue.